# How to Create an image using a text and degree to rotate a text

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, rotation

I want to write a function that accept a string argument as "TEXT" and int argument as "DEGREE" and create a png image write the "TEXT" with rotate it with value "DEGREE".

may any body help me write this please

thanks

---

**EDIT 1)**

I try this before :

```
public System.Drawing.Bitmap WaterText(Bitmap MainImage,
                                           string Text,
                                           byte Alpha,
                                           byte Size,
                                           string FontName,
                                           string StringColor,
                                           byte MyStyle,
                                           byte MyPosision)
    {
        FontStyle Style;
        switch (MyStyle)
        {
            case 1:
                Style = FontStyle.Regular;
                break;
            case 2:
                Style = FontStyle.Bold;
                break;
            case 3:
                Style = FontStyle.Italic;
                break;
            case 4:
                Style = FontStyle.Underline;
                break;
            default:
                Style = FontStyle.Regular;
                break;
        }
        Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision Posision;
        switch (MyPosision)
        {
            case 1:
                Posision = Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Top;
                break;
            case 2:
                Posision = Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Middle;
                break;
            case 3:
                Posision = Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Bottom;
                break;
            default:
                Posision = Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Bottom;
                break;
        }
        Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(MainImage);
        Color Color = HexToColor(StringColor,Alpha);
        StringFormat strformat=new StringFormat();
        strformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        switch (Posision)
        {
            case Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Top:
                strformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                break;
            case Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Middle:
                //canvas.DrawString(Text, new Font(FontName, Size, Style), new SolidBrush(Color), 0, MainImage.Height/2);
                strformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case Florist.APPCode.Struct.TextPosision.Bottom:
                strformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
            default:
                strformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
        }

        canvas.DrawString(Text, new Font(FontName, Size,Style), new SolidBrush(Color),
                new RectangleF(0, 0, MainImage.Width, MainImage.Height), strformat);

        return MainImage;            
    }
```

but now I want to rotate text

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: So, does that code work? Where are you supplying an angle?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://igloocoder.com/archive/2010/06/09/rotating-text-using-graphics.drawstring.aspx) which illustrates how you could rotate a string when drawing to a graphics. It uses the [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing out the string, apply a [`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx) on the `Graphics` object using the angle:

```
canvas.RotateTransform(angle);
```